# CCArray pointer becomes invalid and somehow becomes valid again

Tags: c++, memory-management, cocos2d-iphone, cocos2d-x

**UPDATE (SOLVED. More info at end.)**

I am using a `CCArray` to store `CCSprite` pointers. First I am calling `highlightPoints()` in which the `CCArray` is initialised and retained. Then, `onTouchesMoved` is called in which the `spriteArr` returns null and does not satisfy the `if` condition. But, later when I call `removePoints()`, `spriteArr` remembers all the CCSprites that were added earlier and I am able to remove them from the layer. I am totally confused why this is happening?

**CODE**

```
void Structure::highlightPoints() {
    spriteArr = CCArray::createWithCapacity(mScreenVertices.size());
    spriteArr->retain();
    for( int index = 0; index < mScreenVertices.size(); index++) {

        CCSprite *vertex = CCSprite::create("reticle.png");
        vertex->setPosition(ccp(mScreenVertices.at(index).GetX(), mScreenVertices.at(index).GetY()));

        addChild(vertex);
        spriteArr->addObject(vertex);
    }
}

void Structure::onTouchesMoved(cocos2d::CCPoint position) {
    if(spriteArr) {//false
            for( int index = 0; index < spriteArr->count(); index++) {
                ((CCNode*)spriteArr->objectAtIndex(index))->setPosition(ccp(mScreenVertices.at(index).GetX(), mScreenVertices.at(index).GetY()));
            }
        }
}
void Structure::removePoints() {
    if(spriteArr) {  
        for( int index = 0; index < spriteArr->count(); index++) {
            removeChild((CCNode*)spriteArr->objectAtIndex(index), true);    
        }
    }

}
```

**Solved**

I reliazed I was calling `highlightPoints()` and `removePoints()` using the derived class object and `onTouchesMoved()` using the Base class object. And due to the 'slicing' error the derived class members were unreadable.

Comment: Maybe it is different Structure objects? For example you fill spriteArr in first object, then receive onTouchesMoved in another one.

Comment: In the current case I have 2 structure objects. In both objects' `onTouchesMoved()` I am getting invalid pointer.

Comment: Are you sure that exactly that object's onTouchesMoved gets called?